# Visiting array elements recursively (out of index issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, loops

Assumption: For a 2 dimentional array like `A[r,c]`,

I need to get `A[lastIndex,0]` for `A[-1, lastIndex+1]`. Here -1 is `firstIndex-1`

I will use it for a comparison like:

```
 if (A[r, c] < A[r-1, c + 1] + A[r-1, c + 2])
 {
     execTime -= A[r, c];
 }
```

and needless to say that I am getting `out of index` issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: What are the initial values for `r` and `c` and what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: cannot understand what you want....

Comment: r and c are not static. This is a part of complex structure so i cannot explain but i just need to start from beginning when it is out of index while comparing elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use array dimention as division modulus to derive the index:

```
A[(r-1 + A.GetLength(0)) % A.GetLength(0), c + 1]
```

For `r >= 1` this will be just `r-1`, and for `r == 0` this will give you `A.GetLength(0) - 1`, which is the last index.

Comment: @samet, if you need this index to rotate as well - do the very same thing, just use `A.GetLength(1)`